# img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, histogram, cascade

I try combine haar cascade code with histogram code

I try this code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Cascade jeruk
jeruk_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

base1 = cv2.imread('base1.png')
base2 = cv2.imread('base2.png')
base3 = cv2.imread('base3.png')

#Set hist parameters
hist_height = 64
hist_width = 256
nbins = 32
bin_width = hist_width/nbins
hrange = [0,180]
srange = [0,256]
ranges = hrange+srange                                  # ranges =   [0,180,0,256]

#Create an empty image for the histogram
h = np.zeros((hist_height,hist_width))

while 1:
    grabbed, img = camera.read()
    cam = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    if not grabbed:
      "Camera could not be started."
      break

    # add this
    # image, reject levels level weights.
    jeruks = jeruk_cascade.detectMultiScale(cam, 1.03, 5)

    # add this
    for (x,y,w,h) in jeruks:

    #    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(17,126,234),2)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(img,'Jeruk',(x+w,y+h), font, 1, (17,126,234), 2, cv2.LINE_AA) #---write the text

        roi_gray = cam[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

I add this histogram code

```
    histcam = cv2.calcHist([cam], [0], None, [nbins], [0,256])
    cv2.normalize(histcam,histcam, hist_height, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    hist=np.int32(np.around(histcam))

    for x,y in enumerate(hist):
        cv2.rectangle(h,(x*bin_width,y),(x*bin_width + bin_width-1,hist_height), (255), -1)

    #Flip upside down
    h=np.flipud(h)

#Show the histogram
    cv2.imshow('Color Histogram',h)
    h = np.zeros((hist_height,hist_width))

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

after I run all of them, I got this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/arizal/Documents/cascade jeruk/histogram/project1.py", line 52, in
>
> cv2.rectangle(h,(x*bin_width,y),(x*bin_width + bin_width-1,hist_height), (255), -1)
>
> TypeError: img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

the error in line 52 :

```
cv2.rectangle(h,(x*bin_width,y),(x*bin_width + bin_width-1,hist_height), (255), -1)
```

but if I remove cascade code, the histogram code can run without error with the same histogram code ? how to fix it ?

Comment: can you print type(h) and h.dtype before that line?

Comment: print to terminal using print function ? @api55

Comment: yes, i mean it is not a solution, but probably will tell what it is and maybe it can help to determine the problem

Comment: I print : h = np.zeros((hist_height,hist_width)) in line line 24, 

this the result :

('h : ', array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ...,
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]))

@api55

Comment: I think thats is array, but why the error say that is not array ??

Comment: i do not know which one is line 24, but you have to print it in such case before the cv2.rectangle instruction... and it is enough to use type and dtype which will reveal the common problems with the array

Comment: i have print type(h) from this line h = np.zeros((hist_height,hist_width)), and this is the result : 
('h : ', array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ...,
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]))
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: and I also print(img) and the result img <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: but why the error say that is not array ?

Comment: does anyone else see my name here `jeruk_cascade`?

Comment: jeruk = orange fruit in english :)

Comment: before the line `for x,y in enumerate(hist):`, try `print h.shape` and `print h.dtype` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
h = np.zeros((hist_height,hist_width))
```

which is indeed a valid array, however it should be specified the dtype to make sure it will be visible in imshow later as it is intended like:

```
h = np.zeros((hist_height,hist_width), dtype=np.uint8)
```

for a normal grey-scale image. However the error comes because you write:

```
for (x,y,w,h) in jeruks:
```

which will put a number in `h` replacing the array you had.

**Solution:**

change the name of `h`, also, try to avoid one letter names, it is bad practice and prone to error, specially in python where the types are not set for a variable.

By the way, this could have been spotted faster and easier, if you write as the comments suggested :

```
print(type(h))
print(h.dtype)
```

before the lines

```
for x,y in enumerate(hist):
    cv2.rectangle(h,(x*bin_width,y),(x*bin_width + bin_width-1,hist_height), (255), -1)
```

You would have obtained something like `int` and an error saying that `h` does not have dtype attribute.

Comment: @ArizalZanuarRisqi no problem :) If the answer solved your question it is good to mark it as the answer, to help people find the answer faster

Answer (score 0):

`camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` this part should be changed.
Try ,
`camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` like this, it worked for me.